# Compute the number of cannonballs in a Pyramid with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Am working on a function that should take a height argument of the pyramid and calculate the number of cannonballs in the pyramid for that height. We are counting from the top square which has one cannonball going downwards to the base square.The square at height 1 has one cannonball, the square at height 2 has 4 cannonballs so in total the pyramid has 5 cannonballs. I have tried doing it with recursion but its not working , here is the code am using so far

```
 function cannonball(h){

    return h**2+cannonball(h-1);
}
console.log(cannonball(8));
```

The function is recursing infinitely and causing a stack range exception, is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved your own problem. Nice work! I thought it would be fun to do a visual representation of `cannonballs`. I hope others can enjoy this puzzle too :D

```js
function* cannonballs (n)
{ if (n == 0) return
  for (const row of cannonballs(n - 1))
    yield ` ${row}`
  yield "".repeat(n)
}

console.log(Array.from(cannonballs(5)).join("\n"))
```

Or we can give the pyramid 3d appearance using ascii -

```js
function* cannonballs (n)
{ if (n == 0) return
  for (const row of cannonballs(n - 1))
    yield `  ${row}`
  yield "(  )".repeat(n) + ")".repeat(n - 1)
}

console.log(Array.from(cannonballs(5)).join("\n"))
```

```
        (  )        
      (  )(  ))      
    (  )(  )(  )))    
  (  )(  )(  )(  ))))  
(  )(  )(  )(  )(  )))))
```

Comment: Can you edit to allow user pass a height argument of his choice?

Comment: @Source_Code_001 the height parameter is `n` and in this example `n = 5`, as you see in `cannonballs(5)`. Try writing `cannonballs(7)` to see a larger pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

The function needed an if statement, now its working as it should

```
function cannonball(h){
if(h<2){
    return h;
   }else{
     return h**2+cannonball(h-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: change `h == 1` to `h < 2` so that `cannonball(1)` and `cannonball(0)` return the correct result :D